# Bash, openssl, strange behavior on exit status

Tags: bash, openssl, exit-code

I'm writing a script that should do a dictionary attack on a text file passed as argument encrypted with openssl.
Here is what I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
# written by Cosimo Colaci

passwords=( $(cat italian.txt) ) # italian.txt is a list of words

for word in ${passwords[@]}
  do
    openssl enc -d -aes-128-cfb1 -in "$1" -k $word 2>/tmp/err
    pid=$$
    wait $pid
    if [ -s /tmp/err ]
    then
      continue
    else
      openssl enc -d -aes-128-cfb1 -in "$1" -k $word;
      break;
    fi
  done
```

I also tried

```
for word in ${passwords[@]}
  do
    openssl enc -d -aes-128-cfb1 -in "$1" -k $word &>/dev/null
    exitstatus=$?
    if [ $exitstatus -ne 0 ]
    then
      continue
    else
      openssl enc -d -aes-128-cfb1 -in "$1" -k $word;
      break;
    fi
  done
```

The problem is that on some cicles the exit status is 0 even if decription fails, as I can see by launching:
`bash -x ./crack_italian.sh filetodecript.txt`
but the same command, in a terminal, behave as expected and fails.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read -r word; do
    if openssl enc -d -aes-128-cfb1 -in "$1" -k "$word" >openssl.out 2>&1
    then
        cat openssl.out
        break
    fi
done <italian.txt

rm -f openssl.out
```

- You don't need to read the file into an array.
- You can use the exit status *directly* in an `if` statement.  Note that in your second example, the assignment of `$?` to `exitstatus` changes `$?`.
- Variable expansions should be double quoted.

Slightly shorter:

```
while read -r word; do
    openssl enc -d -aes-128-cfb1 -in "$1" -k "$word" >openssl.out 2>&1 &&
    { cat openssl.out; break; }
done <italian.txt

rm -f openssl.out
```

Comment: A further simplification wouldn't use the temporary file at all, but would capture content into a shell variable via command substitution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It appears as if the user wants to look at the result, which is why they run `openssl` a second time. If they need the output for anything later, it will be available in the file. I dislike putting program output into variables, unless it's simple short strings. Note: I have no clue what `openssl` actually outputs in the above code.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected with your suggests, but still have the same problem:
openssl gives an exit status 0 on a wrong password, even in the terminal...

Comment: @Alex_DeLarge The only `openssl` subcommand that exit codes are actually defined for in the manual is `openssl smime`. If you decrypt a string using a password, then I assume `openssl` has no way of telling whether the decrypted data is actually makes sense to the user given the password. I.e. `openssl` don't know whether the password is correct or not.

Comment: right... even if with some passwords give exit status 1, maybe for some words it can recognize the bad decription... however, I solved with this:
`| iconv -f utf-8 -t ucs-4`
since my file to decrypt is in UTF8, if iconv gives error, so decryption fails.
Thank you again, and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I agree that they want to look at the result. I don't see a point to `openssl ... >file`, *especially* with a constant filename (which means more than one instance of the script can't safely run at a time, and that it's prone to symlink attacks), when one could `result=$(openssl ...)` and then `printf '%s\n' "$openssl"` on success.